# Bootstrap select searchable select within another dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

Please see this fiddle. If you put the bootstrap select library inside another dropdown it doesn't display the select contents.

https://jsfiddle.net/75cndb4a/1/

```
Click link above.
```

Is there some css or js I can add that will make it display within a dropdown?

Answer (score 2):

Html structure is changed and updated in the below fiddle.

`Check this`[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/5c9b9t9n/)

Comment: doesnt work in bootstrap 4.1.3 css 4.1.3 js and 1.13.1 bootstrap select